# GestureDetector with child button: prevent onTapDown call

Tags: flutter

I have a `GestureDetector` with `CupertinoButton` inside. How to prevent passing touches up the tree when tapping on the button?

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(const App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: GestureDetector(
        onTapDown: (details) => debugPrint('onTapDown'),
        child: Center(
            child: CupertinoButton(
          child: Text('Tap'),
          onPressed: () {},
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In my example, I don't want `onTapDown` to be printed when the button is tapped.
Using `Stack` is not an option for me, sorry.

Comment: But why do you want to use it this way? You can also use `InkWell` and it will not work when the button is clicked.

Comment: @LalitFauzdar that's the requirement. `GestureRecognizer` is needed to scale up/down the container.

Comment: if you want to "scale up/down" (whatever it is) then `onScale*` callbacks should be used, what do you need `onTapDown` for?

Comment: @pskink I really don't want to dive deep into the business requirements. I appreciate suggesting alternatives, but they aren't suitable for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Add `behavior` property of GestureDetector to `HitTestBehavior.opaque`

Full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
        onTapDown: (details) => debugPrint('onTapDown'),
        child: Center(
            child: CupertinoButton(
          child: const Text('Tap'),
          onPressed: () => debugPrint('Tap'),
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Not working. `onTapDown` is called when I tap the button.